# Regex to check if a string contains at least A-Za-z0-9 but not an &

Tags: regex

I am trying to check  if a string contains at least A-Za-z0-9 but not an &.
My experience with regexes is limited, so I started with the easy part and got:

```
.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*
```

However I am having troubling combining this with the does not contain an & portion.
I was thinking along the lines of `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9].*)(?![&()]).*` but that does not seem to do the trick.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Java, but we annotation based validation so I'm using @Pattern

Comment: I think there is callback method somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this what you meant, but here is a regular expression that will match any string that:

- contains at least one alpha-numeric character
- does not contain a &

This expression ensures that the entire string is always matched (the `^` and `$` at beginning and end), and that none of the characters matched are a "&" sign (the `[^&]*` sections):

```
^[^&]*[a-zA-Z0-9][^&]*$
```

However, it might be clearer in code to simply perform two checks, if you are not limited to a single expression.

Also, check out the `\w` class in regular expressions (it might be the better solution for catching alphanumeric chars if you want to allow non-ASCII characters).