# Regex: Validate if a string is [a-zA-Z0-9] only, 8+ chars, has at least one of lowercase, uppercase, digits

Tags: regex

The question is pretty much in the title. I need to check if a string is alphanumerical only - no special characters, and that is contains at least one lowercase letter, at least one uppercase letter, at least one number.

`passWORD1` validates, `password2, PASSWORD3, passWORD, passWORD5*, psWD6` would not.

It is similar to [Regex to check if a string contains at least A-Za-z0-9 but not an &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839543/regex-to-check-if-a-string-contains-at-least-a-za-z0-9-but-not-an), but does not meet all the criteria. I also could go with [iterating through the criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839543/regex-to-check-if-a-string-contains-at-least-a-za-z0-9-but-not-an), but I really need a regex to feed it to [validate.js](https://validatejs.org/) module (so JS/Node), which will only throw one a single error stating all the password criteria at once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$"

^ Start of the string
(?=.*[a-z]) lowercase validation
(?=.*[A-Z]) uppercase validation
(?=.*\d) numbers validation
[a-zA-Z\d] characters allowed
{8,} minimum size (you can put the maximum after the comma)
$ End of the String
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need fulfilling all your requirement is this,

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9]*[a-z])(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[a-z0-9]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$
```

You basically need three **[positive look aheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** to ensure meeting your three conditions of minimum presence of three kind of characters and finally consume the alphanumeric characters using a character set followed by quantifier as mentioned in the regex.

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?=[A-Z0-9]*[a-z])` - Look ahead to ensure at least one lower case alphabet
- `(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])` - Look ahead to ensure at least one digit
- `(?=[a-z0-9]*[A-Z])` - Look ahead to ensure at least one upper case alphabet
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}` - Captures eight or more alphanumeric characters
- `$` - Matches end of string

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oi4yEQ/1)**

Comment: a special char invalidates this regex. Op asked for those conditions -at least-

Comment: @BecarioSenior: Well, if you read OP's post a little carefully, he clearly mentions "I need to check if a string is alphanumerical only - no special characters". So yes, if the input contains special chars then it should not match like OP expected. Or, were you trying to make some other point I didn't get?